# Appending to List within a Dictionary

Tags: python

Objective:  Append items from `value['itemArray']` to `Products['Items']` - see function `fba_orders`

Problem: The Current code only appends the last item of `value['itemArray']` to `Products['Items']`

Current Output:

```
{'Items': [{'SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId': 266804219, 'SellerSKU': 'IX-GZ31-31K6', 'Quantity': 1}, {'SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId': 266804219, 'SellerSKU': 'IX-GZ31-31K6', 'Quantity': 1}]}
```

Correct Output would be:

```
{'Items': [{'SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId': 266804218, 'SellerSKU': 'KM-090914-840-BEARLAPTOP', 'Quantity': 1}, {'SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId': 266804219, 'SellerSKU': 'IX-GZ31-31K6', 'Quantity': 1}]}
```

Code:

```
import sys

VALUE = {'amountPaid': '43.38',
 'amountSaved': 0.0,
 'buyerCheckoutMessage': '',
 'buyerUserID': 13182254,
 'buyerUserName': 'W5Tiny',
 'checkoutStatus': {'status': 'Complete'},
 'createdTime': '2015-06-30T22:41:01Z',
 'creatingUserRole': 'Buyer',
 'itemArray': [{'item': {'itemID': 266804218,
    'price': '21.1',
    'quantity': 1,
    'sellerInventoryID': 'KM-090914-840-BEARLAPTOP',
    'sk': 'KM-090914-840-BEARLAPTOP',
    'title': u"VTech Bear's Baby Laptop, Blue [Toy]"}},
  {'item': {'itemID': 266804219,
    'price': '22.28',
    'quantity': 1,
    'sellerInventoryID': 'IX-GZ31-31K6',
    'sk': 'IX-GZ31-31K6',
     'title': 'Toy State Caterpillar Push Powered Rev It Up Dump Truck     [Toy]'}}],
 'orderID': 34013525,
 'orderStatus': 'Completed',
 'paidTime': '2015-06-30T22:50:38Z',
 'shippingAddress': {'addressID': 15798541,
  'cityName': 'Nashville',
  'country': 'US',
  'countryName': None,
  'name': 'UNKNOWN',
  'postalCode': '37221',
  'stateOrProvince': 'TN',
  'street1': '123 BOOGIE DRIVE',
  'street2': None},
 'shippingDetails': {'amount': '0.0',
  'insuranceFee': 0,
  'servicesArray': [],
  'shippingService': 'Standard shipping'},
 'subtotal': 43.38,
 'taxAmount': 0.0,
 'total': '43.38',
 'transactionArray': {'transaction': {'buyer': {'email':   'fakewilson259612@hotmail.com'},
   'finalValueFee': '0.0',
   'providerID': '11V84334FD304010L',
   'providerName': 'Paypal'}}}


def fba_order():
    address = {}
    products = {'Items': []}
    item = {}
    Items = []
    address['City'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['cityName']
    address['CountryCode'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['country']
    address['Line1'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['street1']
    address['Line2'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['street2']
    address['Name'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['name']
    address['PostalCode'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['postalCode']
    address['StateOrProvinceCode'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['stateOrProvince']
    for items in VALUE['itemArray']:
        item['Quantity'] = items['item']['quantity']
        item['SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId'] = items['item']['itemID']
        item['SellerSKU'] = items['item']['sk']
        products['Items'].append(item)
        continue
    print address, '\n', products

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(fba_order())
```

Comment: `item` is a dict object. You append the same `item` object twice. You should initiate `item={}` in `for` loop

Answer (score 3):

You are reusing the dictionary referenced by `item` over and over again; appending this one dictionary won't create a new copy. Rather, you are adding multiple references to that one dictionary. As you continue to alter the dictionary all those references will show those changes.

Better produce an entirely new dictionary for each loop iteration:

```
for items in VALUE['itemArray']:
    item = {
        'Quantity': items['item']['quantity'],
        'SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId': items['item']['itemID']
        'SellerSKU': items['item']['sk'],
    }
    products['Items'].append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks you... this was driving me crazy

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are creating item outside the `for` loop and then just changing the values inside the for loop and appending it to the list.

dictionaries are reference, and hence even after appending to `products['Items']` list if you change the `item` dictionary it will make changes to the `item` that was appended to the list.

You want to initialize `item` to a new dictionary inside the `for` loop.

Example -

```
def fba_order():
    address = {}
    products = {'Items': []}
    Items = []
    address['City'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['cityName']
    address['CountryCode'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['country']
    address['Line1'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['street1']
    address['Line2'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['street2']
    address['Name'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['name']
    address['PostalCode'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['postalCode']
    address['StateOrProvinceCode'] = VALUE['shippingAddress']['stateOrProvince']
    for items in VALUE['itemArray']:
        item = {}
        item['Quantity'] = items['item']['quantity']
        item['SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId'] = items['item']['itemID']
        item['SellerSKU'] = items['item']['sk']
        products['Items'].append(item)
        continue
    print address, '\n', products
```