# Appending to pre-populated list within a dictionary of lists alters all lists within dictionary

Tags: python

I'm attempting to sort some values into a dictionary of lists using string prefixes. Here is the basic code I am running:

```
values = ["a_one", "a_two", "b_three", "b_four", "c_five", "c_six"]
value_groups = {"a": [],
                "b": [],
                "c": []}

for value in values:
    for prefix in value_groups.keys():
        if value.startswith(prefix):
            value_groups[prefix].append(value)
            break
```

The desired, and actual, output of this code is:

```
value_groups = {"a": ["a_one", "a_two"],
                "b": ["b_three", "b_four"],
                "c": ["c_five", "c_six"]}
```

So the code above works as-is.

My problem arises when I initialize the lists within `value_groups` with one or more strings. In this case, every `value` in `values` gets appended to every list within `value_groups`. Non-functional code below:

```
values = ["a_one", "a_two", "b_three", "b_four", "c_five", "c_six"]
# ---START OF EDITED CODE---
initial_list = ["x", "y", "z"]
value_groups = {"a": initial_list,
                "b": initial_list,
                "c": initial_list}
# ---END OF EDITED CODE---

for value in values:
    for prefix in value_groups.keys():
        if value.startswith(prefix):
            value_groups[prefix].append(value)
            break
```

The desired output of this code would be:

```
value_groups = {"a": ["x", "y", "z", "a_one", "a_two"],
                "b": ["x", "y", "z", "b_three", "b_four"],
                "c": ["x", "y", "z", "c_five", "c_six"]}
```

But instead, I am getting three identical lists within `value_groups`:

```
value_groups = {"a": ["x", "y", "z", "a_one", "a_two",
                      "b_three", "b_four", "c_five", "c_six"], 
                "b": ["x", "y", "z", "a_one", "a_two",
                      "b_three", "b_four", "c_five", "c_six"], 
                "c": ["x", "y", "z", "a_one", "a_two",
                      "b_three", "b_four", "c_five", "c_six"]}
```

My intuition (and [preliminary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168071/appending-to-list-within-a-dictionary) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113547/append-a-list-to-a-list-within-a-dictionary-in-python) [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168071/appending-to-list-within-a-dictionary)) is that there is some sort of memory referencing mechanism that I am running afoul of, but I am not quite sure what it is. Anyone out there able to explain it to me? (if that is, indeed, the problem...)

Comment: That behaviour does not happen with the code you've posted.

Comment: Did the code run as expected for you?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that's not how you're defining `value_groups`.  What you've probably done is something like `value_groups = {"a": some_list, "b": some_list, "c": some_list}` where `some_list` was previously defined.  If that's the case, every key in the dict refers to *the same list*. A fix would be to make copies of `some_list` with an empty slice: `{"a": some_list[:], "b": some_list[:], "c": some_list[:]}`

Comment: Run it and see! You're maybe using fromkeys, per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8174723/3001761

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, yep, that was the problem. Thanks for the answer and for correctly quessing that I did not properly translate my code to here.

Comment: The question received upvotes as well (probably after the fix). An upvote is worth 5x as much as a downvote in terms of reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value_groups = {"a": ["x", "y", "z"],
                "b": ["x", "y", "z"],
                "c": ["x", "y", "z"]}
```

I'm pretty certain that's not how you're defining `value_groups`.  What you've probably done is something like this (where `some_list` was previously defined):

```
some_list = ["x", "y", "z"]
value_groups = {"a": some_list, 
                "b": some_list, 
                "c": some_list}
```

If that's the case, every key in the dict refers to *the same list*. A fix would be to make copies of `some_list` using `some_list.copy()` (or by copying with an empty slice `some_list[:]`):

```
some_list = ["x", "y", "z"]
value_groups = {"a": some_list.copy(), 
                "b": some_list.copy(), 
                "c": some_list.copy()}
```

Comment: Good job intuiting the actual problem.  I was looking at the OP's posting and thought "wait a minute! Python doesn't assume initializing lists with the same constant data means they are the same list!"  Good job reading between the lines.  I've had to do that occasionally on SO when the OP doesn't actually test their sample code to ensure it exhibits the problem behavior.

Comment: You can also use `some_list.copy()`

Comment: Sorry for the noob boo-boo of not testing the sample code :(

Comment: @ChefPaul92  It's not just a noob problem.  I'm no noob in Python, but I've been known to quick type or edit a bit of code without testing it.  (More than once).